How can I power my 12 V solar pump?
I have a 12 V submersable solar water pump:
the specifications are as follows:
DC12V
Power 160 watt
14 amp
Can I power it with a 12 V Power Supply normally use for LED lights:
12 V
150 watt
10 amp

You answered your own question, but it won't work. The DC power supply cannot supply 14 amps, and you will burn up the power supply trying. Good luck.

What size of Solar Panel do I get to power this pump? Will I need a Regulator as well?
